# How can I see server logs in Ruby on Rails daemon way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon, production-environment

Now I am running a Ruby on Rails app in Daemon way on my EC2 instance(AWS)...

```
"bundle exec rails server -e production -d"
```

In this case, I am not sure how I can see the server logs.
Actually, there is not any log file in `logs/` directory.
Please let me know if you have any idea or hint.

Thanks.

Comment: `tail -f log/production.log` this what i do from rails app directory

Comment: Actually, it is empty in log/ directory.  There isn't any log file (production.log, development.log).   I am not sure why that is.

Comment: I know, your question is `How can I see server logs in Ruby on Rails daemon way?`, for  `I am not sure why that is.` you need to debug and add some more details, so someone will surely help you to fix it :)

Comment: So what should I do exactly?  Just in order to see the logs..

Comment: what is the webserver you are using

Comment: Currently I am using Nginx.

Comment: Are you using webkit? puma? unicorn? What is the webserver of your application?

Comment: How is the logger configured in your `config/environment.rb` or your `config/environments/production.rb`?

Comment: I am using Puma.

Comment: What should I add or change in config/environments/production.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f log-path/*
```

find the log folder in the ec2 instance under /var/log folder

find the exact path and replace the log-path

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Puma, you need to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to specific files as shown [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/examples/config.rb#L49)

```
# Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to files specified. The 3rd parameter
# ("append") specifies whether the output is appended, the default is
# "false".
#
stdout_redirect '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr'
stdout_redirect '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr', true
```

Comment: So where can I find config.rb in Puma?   I am asking about the absolute path of the file on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

With this gem, you can read logs in browser: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/sweet_staging

in addition, execute ruby code in a simple console and call unix commands